# How to access profile permissions via API

Tags: apex, api, permissions, profile, security

If I know the name of a certain profile, I would like to obtain CRUD permission settings for each object in the profile using Apex.

I see that there is an sObject called *Profile*, but this only reveals the boolean values of permissions such as *Edit Case Comments*, or *Transfer Cases* etc.

There is another sObject called *ObjectPermissions* which you can get this info from, but this is only for *Permission Sets* and **not** for *Profiles*.

I would like to determine whether a certain profile can read and edit Case records just as the *ObjectPermissions* sObject allows you to do for *Permission Sets*.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Actually, the PermissionSet SObject has a field in it called IsOwnedByProfile. Take a look at this blog post by Adam Torman, http://blogs.developerforce.com/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html:

> This field determines whether a permission set is a custom one or if
>   it is parented by a profile. This is made possible because for every
>   profile, there is one underlying permission set. That way, permissions
>   layer equally across permission sets without having to treat a profile
>   differently.

So, if you want to find the CRUD permissions of a profile you can do something like this:

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE parentid in (select id from permissionset where
PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
```

Comment: Nice one Daniel, I was searching for this myself, since the question relates to know what is set on a profile rather than the current users permissions. Was about to break out the Metadata API from Apex! ;-)

Comment: That's great. Thanks Daniel. I wondered why I was getting so many permission sets returned when I was playing around with some SOQL queries before. I will try and put this to good use.

Comment: Awesome Daniel! Thanks for the call out as well!! Please keep in mind that accessing PermissionSetAssignment, PermissionSet, ObjectPermissions, FieldPermissions, or SetupEntityAccess for a Profile is read-only - you can't update these permissions or assignments using Permission Sets that are owned by profiles.

Comment: Great post!  I note that if you use profile 'Read Only' in the subquery's where clause, you will not get back any ObjectPermissions for SObjects other than Account, Case, Lead, Opportunity and a few others. No custom SObjects at all.

Comment: @crop1645 - did you find that on any other profiles other than 'Read Only'? Sounds like a bug if it's isolated to just that one profile.

Comment: @Adam Torman : Profile 'Chatter External User', 'Chatter Free User', 'Chatter Moderator User' - return no rows; 'Contract Manager', 'Marketing User', 'Read Only', 'Solution Manager', 'Standard User' all return only out-of-box SFDC SObjects. So, I would conclude that the above solution works  for custom profiles + profile System Administrator

Comment: years later, but @crop1645 -- there will only be ObjectPermissions records for SObjects that that profile has CRUD Permissions on. If you never updated any of the standard profiles to have CRUD on an object, it won't show up.

Answer (score 8):

Doing this is pretty much possible both in Apex and Visualforce code. The platform gives rich describe information and shorthands which check the current user's CRUD or FLS permissions.

Here are few code snippets

To know if few fields are accessible

```
<apex:outputText value="{!accountBillingAddress}" rendered="{!AND($ObjectType.Account.fields.BillingCity.Accessible, $ObjectType.Account.fields.BillingState.Accessible)}"/>
```

To check the same in Apex code

```
     if (Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.BillingCity.isAccessible()
          &&
        Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.BillingState.isAccessible()  
        ){ }
```

Similarly individual objects can be checked as well, for ex:

```
<apex:relatedList list="Contacts" rendered="{!$ObjectType.Case.accessible}"/>
```

This guide has lot of rich details about secure coding guidelines for further reading: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_Guideline

Source : VF Dev guide (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_std_checking_accessibility.htm) and Developer force WIKI

Comment: Describe calls (from Apex or VF) work only for current $User. Given that OP is talking about name of given profile I don't think he wants to use it only for current user...