# Check user permissions through REST-API

Tags: rest-api, permissions

Is there a way to check whether current user has certain permission via REST API? Preferably without using metadata APIs.

Comment: What permission are you looking for in particular? A setting driven by profiles or permission sets? Or access to an object, field, record type, etc?

Comment: Well, basically any, but most importantly the Modify All Data one. If there is an option of checking write permissions to particular objects, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the Metadata API is the only way to do this. I don't believe it is possible to get that explicit setting via APEX, SOQL, or Describes.

The answer to this similar question sums up another option if you care more about the actual access to Objects rather than the explicit Modify All Data setting: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16533/411. In that case, you'd likely want to create a [REST Endpoint](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST) that wraps some of that logic.

Comment: I was hoping there is a way besides Metadata API. Going as far as creating a REST endpoint is too much for my requirements, but your answer clarifies the matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, you are asking if you remove the "Create" (or other) permission from a users profile (under "Custom Object Permissions") for a particular object, is there are way to check if the user can create that object via the REST API.

The answer is yes.  You can use the REST API Describe call (/services/data/v28.0/sobjects/`<your-custom-object>`/describe), and the results contain what you need - in this example, the "createable" property contains the "Create" permission from a users profile for this object.  There is also, "deletable", "updateable", etc.

Comment: I think you are having the metadata API in mind, which the OP asked to not use. Still, very useful I think, thanks for pointing that out. Here is a link to recent documentation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_basic_info.htm