# User Accessibility on Object Via Apex Code (Not for Logged In user )

Tags: apex

Please Note :

> Not for Current Logged in User

How to find a particular user A has what access on particular object (Read or Create access) say on Account Via Apex Class.

Comment: Are you asking how to do this in the Test context or outside of the Test context.

Comment: @eric, not in test context. that we can do I guess using system.runAs. But I want to  know outside of Test Context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this information is what you want:

[How to access profile permissions via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/how-to-access-profile-permissions-via-api)

Basically you will need to query the ObjectPermissions sObject since every profile has at least one underlying Permission set

```
SELECT Id, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE parentid in (select id from permissionset where
PermissionSet.Profile.Name = 'System Administrator')
```

Comment: It will not work out as I can have an user associated with a profile and that profile is having read access to say Account. Now I created  a permission set and associated with  user which gives Create access to user. So only by profile we wont be able to find out if user as access to an Object(Account) or not. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You do not create a profileset Every profile has a system underlying profile set according to the post. Read the blog entry in the post and you will see.

Comment: I am not talking about Profile Set. I am talking about "Permission Set"  which can be associated at any user. With the "Permission Set" user can have access to Object even if they do not have the access at profile level.

Comment: k, then you will have to cycle through both the profile and permission set to see in total what access they have....This is the only way to currently do it outside of test methods

Comment: ,Thanks for your support. Let me check if it works. I will update on my findings.

Comment: @crmprogdev - No, the OP is talking about Object Level access, not record level access.

Comment: Sorry, I was reading the comments and lost track of the original question. Will delete my comments as they add nothing to this this.